# Sidekiq fails to find records in my database 50% of the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Here's my job:

```
MessageJob.perform_later(@recipient.id.to_s, @sender.id.to_s, @message.body)
```

50% of the times I get the following error in my sidekiq console and the job doesnt get executed.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=369
```

Any idea why it's the case? The record exists long before the job is sent to queu so it's not linked to the after_create / after_commit issue.

Comment: Please share more relevant code, like implementation of `MessageJob#perform` or even the whole class

Comment: @Hugo maybe either `@recipient` or `@sender` already got "destroyed" at the time when the job is performed by sidekiq? Also, how did you know or what made you sure that it failed 50% of the time? Because assuming that it is not 50% of the time, I can think of still some other reasons: like a lot of jobs have failed, but then retried in the future where they no longer exist. Additionally, can you try inserting both `puts @recipient.reload.id` and `puts @sender.reload.id` just above `MessageJob.perform_later(...)`? This eliminates some of the possible causes.

Comment: I've created another thread to make things more clear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891632/sidekiq-not-finding-records-for-rails-active-job closing this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sidekiq not finding records for Rails Active Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891632/sidekiq-not-finding-records-for-rails-active-job)