# Sidekiq not finding records for Rails Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Jobs are queued on after a user is created like so in the model

**user.rb**

```
after_create_commit :profile_photo_job

def profile_photo_job
    message = "Add a profile photo"
    ReminderJob.set(wait: 1800).perform_later(self.id.to_s, message)
end
```

**reminder_job.rb**

```
class ReminderJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id, message)
    if user_id
      user = User.find(user_id)
    end
    ##sending message notification here
  end

end
```

However, it often throws the following error inside my sidekiq console

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=7749
>   Processor: User-MacBook-Pro.local:*****

This error happens in production.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with **workers** returning the error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'`

I tried a bunch of things and realised I had **2 separate Rails apps** (with different databases) reading from the **same queue**. Silly error, but once I changed the queue name for one of the apps, I never saw this again.

Leaving this here if someone hasn't checked this ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In User.rb

```
after_commit :profile_photo_job, on: :create

def profile_photo_job
    message = "Add a profile photo"
    ReminderJob.set(wait: 1800).perform_later(self.id.to_s, message)
end
```

Comment: isnt after_create_commit and after_commit, on: :create the same thing?

Comment: The reason for the error, is that sidekiq is looking for the record in the database before the job is completed.

Comment: They're the same, but I have faced issues when I have used `after_create_commit`. btw which version of rails are you using ?

Comment: Also, look at [this](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/12/31/sidekiq-is-too-fast-record-not-found/). Sometimes even though in some applications, I have worked on after using `after_commit` I have still faced the `Record not found` issue and in some  it's resolved.

Comment: Also, why are you converting to string ? `self.id.to_s`

Comment: I don't think this will solve the issue. I have similar errors when queueing jobs with records that exists long before in the database

Comment: Was just a test, in some case it seemed to work but now I think it was just random.

Comment: Can you clear all your old jobs and try it again ? `Sidekiq.redis { |r| puts r.flushall }`

Comment: @Hugo did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same errors on objects that have existed long before in the database.